# SMS sent confirmation via Android Default sms composer

Tags: android, sms

I am able to open default SMS composer screen via implicit intent and able to send sms successfully.

Question: How do i get confirmation programmatically on successful SMS sent.

in onactivity result i am getting Result "0" for both success and unsuccess.

Comment: You'll have to send from your app programmatically, too, in order to get sent and delivery results.

Comment: in u r case we cant achieve dual-sim functionality

Comment: There is no support in the Android SDK for dual-SIM devices, at least through Android 4.4.

Comment: You'll have to decide which trade-off is acceptable, because Sent/Delivery reports are limited to the app sending.